# Validating email in paypal account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

Please suggest how to validate an email account for `paypal`, whether a transaction account in paypal is exists or not before transaction.

In adaptive payment , we can pay through payapl email ids.. Little bit confuse if valid email not found.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to validate the email address. PayPal sends the payment instructions to the email address you specify in Adaptive Payments. If the email address is NOT associated with a PayPal account, PayPal prompts them to setup an account to claim the amount.

Look at the following statement in the [Adaptive Payments API documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/adaptive-payments/)

"Make payments to almost anyone with an email address or mobile phone number, with or without a PayPal account. Recipients who don't have a PayPal account can create one in minutes."

If you still think you want to validate the email address, then the following SO question has some tricks:
[How to validate PayPal account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228963/how-to-validate-paypal-account?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I am new to PayPal integration, i am not sure about Adaptive Payment api. 
But we have a privilege to check whether specific email id having account in PayPal or not using **GetVerifiedStatus** method.

Please use below sandbox wsdl URL for verifying email

URL : https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptiveAccounts?wsdl

Response will be like below

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns2:GetVerifiedStatusResponse xmlns:ns2="http://svcs.paypal.com/types/aa">
         <responseEnvelope>
            <timestamp>2015-07-20T23:42:46.661-07:00</timestamp>
            <ack>Success</ack>
            <correlationId>5cea9a8575ab9</correlationId>
            <build>17345626</build>
         </responseEnvelope>
         <accountStatus>UNVERIFIED</accountStatus>
         <countryCode>IN</countryCode>
         <userInfo>
            <emailAddress>X@X.com</emailAddress>
            <accountType>PERSONAL</accountType>
            <accountId>X</accountId>
            <name>
               <salutation/>
               <firstName>X</firstName>
               <middleName/>
               <lastName>X</lastName>
               <suffix/>
            </name>
            <businessName/>
         </userInfo>
      </ns2:GetVerifiedStatusResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Note: while creating stub don't forgot to set endpoint as below.

```
String endpointURL = "https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptiveAccounts/GetVerifiedStatus";
```

Answer (score 0):

You validate it by using `filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` this will return a boolean of true of false depending on if the email is valid or is not. But thats to see if the email entered is an "Email"

```
$email = "email@example.com";
if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) {
    // Yes it is valid
}else {
    // No it is not valid
}
```

For PayPal account validation please check [Check if paypal email address is a verified user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785537/check-if-paypal-email-address-is-a-verified-user)

Have fun! Hope that helped..